# Collision Filters not working

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi i am trying to get this collision filter to work but i am a little bit stuck...

```
local bad1CollisionFilter1 = { categoryBits = 1, maskBits = 3 }

if ( temp.imgpath == "BCloud1.png" ) then
 physics.addBody( randomStar, { density=2.9, friction=0.5, bounce=0.3, radius=16, filter=bad1CollisionFilter1 } )
end

local collision = function( bad1CollisionFilter1 )
 if bad1CollisionFilter1.phase == 'began' then
   print("Hello i am  CollisionFilter1")
 end
end
```

Any help to get this working is appreciated!

Comment: Where are you adding the event listener for collision?

Comment: Runtime:removeEventListener("bad1CollisionFilter1", collision)

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the Corona API for [`collision`](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection) and [`EventListener`](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/game-edition-collision-detection); you need to **add** an even listener with the body. Add the following statement to your script.

```
Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", collision )
```

where the first argument states that it is a collision event listener and the second argument is the function name; which in your case is `collision`.